# Difference between eager and lazy evaluation in a non-functional language like JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

In functional programming, I learned that lazy evaluation and eager evaluation generate the same result (Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation Book). So, one can change the evaluation semantics without having unexpected results.

However, in a non-functional and industrial programming language like JavaScript, I don't think both semantics generate the result. For example, if a method `object.f(x)` return a value that depends on the object state (e.g., lifetime), lazy and eager evaluation may return different values. In addition, in functional programming, we may also have a different result if a function `f(x)` return a value that depends on, for example, CPU temperature.

So, will lazy and eager evaluation potentially generate different results? Even in a functional programming language.

Comment: for js, it depends on if you consider `this` an argument for methods, since it is runtime controllable.

Comment: @dandavis, an object state means `this`, isn't?

Comment: if you don't use `call/apply/bind` then `this` usage in object methods reflects the properties of the object, which you could consider state. Keep in mind however that objects can be frozen, which is common in immutable/functional style JS, so in that case, the time of function evaluation doesn't affect the returned value. That's also true of any methods that are referentially transparent. Again if we discount `this`, which is reasonable if frozen, then methods can/should be considered pure functions.

Comment: In functional programming, `f(x)` being an actual function of `x` means its result can’t depend on anything other than `x`, so it can’t depend on the CPU temperature. (There can still be differences in behaviour that aren’t captured as the value of f(x), though, like how long it takes to evaluate, how memory is used, whether it crashes.) As for JavaScript (“industrial”?), yes, any function could be stateful, impure, etc. Lazy evaluation at the same level doesn’t make much sense for it.

Comment: javascript is functional language

Comment: @Alexan, javascript is rather an imperative language with features that allow a coder to keep to a functional programming style if they choose to do so.

Comment: In functional programming, objects are immutable, and you can easily evaluate methods lazily if you want. Doesn't matter whether your language of choice is javascript for that.

Comment: Thanks all, so lazy evaluation is not so useful in non-functional language? ...

Comment: @NaiveDeveloper **no**. It's incredibly useful. It just isn't *safe*. You have to use discipline, convention, and 3rd party libraries (e.g. immutable.js) to achieve only some of what the compiler does for you in pure functional language. N.B. there aren't many of those: making lazy evaluation safe requires significant tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

> In functional programming, I learned that lazy evaluation and eager evaluation generate the same result (Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation Book). So, one can change the evaluation semantics without having unexpected results.

The above statement is wrong. Lazy evaluation and eager evaluation do not always generate the same result, and the following example proves it. Haskell code (lazy evaluation):

```hs
> let forever x = forever x
> const 10 (forever 20)
10
```

OCaml code (eager evaluation):

```ml
# let const a b = a;;
val const : 'a -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
# let rec forever x = forever x;;
val forever : 'a -> 'b = <fun>
# const 10 (forever 20);;
^CInterrupted.
```

As you can see, the same expression produces the result `10` in a lazy language whereas it goes into an infinite loop in the eager language.

Comment: I meant if a program (with eager evaluation), that works without exceptions, I can change its evaluation strategy to lazy and get the same result. Anyways, it is a good point what you mention

I think I have to improve my question because of your comments and other observations in order to close this question. What do you think?